# Is every first-countable symmetrizable space perfect?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let us recall that a *symmetric* on a set $X$ is any function $d:X\times X\to[0,\infty)$ such that
for every $x,y\in X$ the following two conditions are satisfied:

- $d(x,y)=0$ if and only if $x=y$;
- $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$.

A topological space $X$ is called *symmetrizable* if there exists a symmetric $d$ on $X$ such that a subset $U\subseteq X$ is open if and only if for every $x\in X$ there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B_d(x,y)\subseteq U$, where $B_d(x,\varepsilon)=\{y\in X:d(x,y)<\varepsilon\}$.

If a symmetric $d$ on $X$ generates a first-countable Hausdorff topology, then for every $x\in X$ and $\varepsilon>0$ the ball $B_d(x;\varepsilon)$ contains $x$ in its interior $B_d(x;\varepsilon)^\circ$. This fact implies that every closed set $F\subseteq X$  is a $G_\delta$-set in $X$ as $F=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigcup_{x\in F}B_d(x;\tfrac1n)^\circ$.
This was a simple proof of the following known

**Fact.** *Every symmetrizable first-countable Hausdorff space is perfect.*

Symmetrizable spaces are $T_1$ but not necessarily Hausdorff. Countable symmetrizable spaces are perfect (being $T_1$-space). So, we naturally arrive to the following problems.

**Problem 1.** *Is every first-countable symmetrizable space perfect?*

**Problem 2.** *Is every second-countable symmetrizable space perfect?*

**Remark 1.** Consider the set $X=\{-\frac1n:n\in\mathbb N\}\cup\{0\}\cup\{\tfrac1n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ endowed with the symmetric
$$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}\max\{x,y\}&\text{if $\max\{x,y\}>0$ and $\min\{x,y\}<0$};\\
\lvert x-y\rvert&\text{if $\max\{x,y\}\le 0$};\\
0&\text{if $x=y$};\\
1&\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
This symmetric generates a first-countable non-Hausdorff topology in which the unit ball $B_d(0,1)=\{-\frac1n:n\ge 2\}\cup\{0\}$ is nowhere dense. So, the standard proof of the perfectness of symmetrizable first-countable Hausdorff spaces does not work in this case. Nonetheless, the symmetrizable space $X$ is countable and hence perfect.

**Remark 2.** There are many examples of non-perfect symmetrizable Hausdorff spaces, see examples of [Bonnett](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-034-02/S0002-9939-1972-0295275-9/S0002-9939-1972-0295275-9.pdf), [Davis-Gruenhage-Nyikos](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0016660X78900296) or [Stephenson](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/C8E40167DC01044622B64BF56BBC56E1/S0008414X00024366a.pdf/symmetrizable-and-weakly-first-countable-spaces.pdf). However all these examples are not first-countable (being Hausdorff).

Comment: @Tyrone It seems that semistratifiable spaces are are assumed to be Hausdorff (if not regular). Semimetrizable spaces can be non-Hausdorff, so those arguments do not work in the non-Hausdorff context.

Comment: On second thought, I agree. My apologies. [Creede](https://msp.org/pjm/1970/32-1/pjm-v32-n1-p05-s.pdf) assumes no separation in his definitions of a semi-stratifiable space, and shows that a $T_1$ space is semimetrisable iff it is first-countable and semistratifiable. However, that every Frechet-Urysohn symmetrisable space is semimetrisable requires $T_2$ separation. An uncountable set in the cofinite topology is a symmetrisable $T_1$ Frechet-Urysohn space which is not semimetrisable and has no $G_\delta$-points.